# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

In my application, I am updating existing contacts or adding them if they are not present. I check for the email id of the contact in the Outlook contacts folder. Update or Create functionality. When I used Outlook 2010, the application worked fine. When updated to Outlook 2016 for the same code, it threw the error.

What I tried for Outlook 2010 and worked until latest Outlook update:

```
List<Contact> result = new List<Contact>();
result = con.Where(x => x.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower())).ToList();
```

This threw "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error in the result= line when Outlook got updated to 2016 version.

//Get all the contacts from Folder. Fetches all contacts

```
      if (contactItems.TotalCount > 0)
            {
                service.LoadPropertiesForItems(contactItems, view.PropertySet);
                foreach (var item in contactItems.Items)
                {
                    if (item is Contact)
                    {
                        con.Add(item as Contact);    
                    }
                }
            }
```

//Search contact whose email address matches

```
List<Contact> result = new List<Contact>();
result = con.Where(x => x.EmailAddresses.Contains(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1).Equals(email)).ToList();
```

Outlook version 2010:

```
result = con.Where(x => x.EmailAddresses[EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1].Address.ToLower().Equals(email.ToLower())).ToList();
```

This worked just fine

Updated Outlook version 2016:
The above logic threw the Key not found exception. So I changed it to:

```
result = con.Where(x => x.EmailAddresses.Contains(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1).Equals(email)).ToList();
```

I want to make a check where both strings are compared with .ToLower as many email ID's have capital letters.

My Doubts:
Why did i get the error?
Is the version change the problem here?

Comment: The *immediate* problem seems to be that you directly try to access the dictionary `x.EmailAddresses` with the key `EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1`. Now, *maybe* up until the update, the "dictionary" was a `HashTable` or some similar old and deprecated structure that *doesn't* complain if you try to access a key that isn't there. Newer "real" dictionaries *do* complain. -- Anyways, you might want to change the `Where` to something like `dictionary.ContainsKey(key) && dictionary[key].Address[...Equals whatever...]`.

Comment: Thank you @Corak What you said is true about the Key not being identified because of the deprecated structure. I still didn't get a solution in code though :( I tried a few approaches. Didn't get a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`TryGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailaddressdictionary.trygetvalue?view=exchange-ews-api) like so:

```
EmailAddress email;
var success = contact.EmailAddresses.TryGetVaue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out email);

if (success)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is what I did

```
foreach (Contact item in contactItems.Items)
                        {
                            if (item is Contact)
                            {
                                    EmailAddress emAdd;
                                    var emailVal = item.EmailAddresses.TryGetValue(EmailAddressKey.EmailAddress1, out emAdd);
```

//List that stores the string format, SMTP email address
                                    con.Add(emAdd.Address);

```
                            }
                        }
```

I then search the List for the email I need. If email is present then contact details are Updated. If email is not present, New contact is created.